# Was there ever a villan who collected Spider-man's discarded webbing or stole his cartridges/webshooters?

Tags: marvel, comics, spider-man, weapon

I feel like enough of Spider-man's enemies have had enough of a background in chemistry and technology to have been able to analyse and replicate spider-man's spider webs. Especially if they stole his web shooters, web cartridges, or even just picked up one of the many webs he leaves around town and analysed it before it dissolved. At the very least, it would have helped them understand it, and maybe even use it or find a counter to it. Have any of them done it?

Comment: Mysterio made a gas that dissolved Spidey's webs way back in *Amazing Spider-Man #13*, and Chameleon used a copycat webbing even earlier in *Amazing Spider-Man #1*.  So the strategy of replicating/countering the webs has been around since the beginning, though we never see either of them explicitly stealing webbing as part of the development process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In *The Inferior Deadpool* #10, Volume #4, Deadpool steals one of Spider-Man's web shooters.

[image: The Inferior Deadpool #10 cover]

The site where I found this image claims it's not the first time Deadpool has done this (click to embiggen).
[image: Deadpool steals a web-shooter]

Comment: Somehow Spidey should've seen this coming.

Comment: I thought Deadpool was an ally of Spidey's?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo: Deadpool falls on the "good" spectrum as a whole, but he is nowhere near other heroes in terms of "always doing good". Take the Punisher as another example. While he tends to kill the bad guys, he does not do it on the principle of doing good, but is driven by vengeance or intolerance. Similarly, Dr. Fries (DC universe, I know, I know) is considered a villain, but he rarely intends to truly harm; he simply puts saving Nora above anything else, whether it's good or bad. Deadpool's motives are less clear (intentionally), but he also does what he wants over what is considered good.

Comment: Well exactly. That makes him an Antihero. It does _not_ make him a villain.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo: Why wouldn't Deadpool be a villain? He kills people, sometimes for money and sometimes just because he feels like it.

Comment: So does Han Solo. Is Han Solo a villain? No. On the alignment spectrum, Deadpool is what you'd call a Chaotic Neutral character. He plays by his own rules and is somewhat unpredictable, but he isn't inherently evil. He has no desires to attain unlimited power or rule / destroy the world, or even defeat the hero, as you'd expect a villain to. Deadpool is just..... Deadpool.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that Spider-man, at this time, has the mind of Otto Octavius (a.k.a, Dr. Octopus). So, Deadpool's hardly the only questionable character in the scene.

Answer (score 4):

In Amazing Spider-Man 546 a villain called Sean Boyle, aka the Spider-Mugger, managed to steal one of Peter Parker's web-shooters. He used it to ensnare people that he wanted to rob, while wearing a Spider-Man mask.

[image]

Sean was killed a few numbers later and never learned the secret of the formula, but at least he realized what a treasure he had found and used it for crime.

Answer (score 2):

In Marvel's Ultimate Comics, [Arcade](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Arcade_(Earth-1610)) is a very rich gamer with a hatred of mutants.  Among other weapons, he utilizes web shooters.  He claims that one of his employees reverse-engineered it "from from some polymer he scraped off a wall in Manhattan".  It was most likely Spider-man's webbing that was reverse-engineered.

The web-shooters seem to have a side-effect though: Arcade just wouldn't shut up, as pointed out by Wolverine.  It seems Parker's loquaciousness is catching.

As a side-note, Arcade was kind of a badass in this arc.  He soundly defeated Nightcrawler, and put up a moderately good fight against the X-men as a whole.

In the mainstream continuity, an argument could be made for Venom to have 'duplicated' Spidey's webs.  When Venom uses webbing, he produces it himself.  It is otherwise very similar to Spider-man's.  Like Spidey, Venom's webs last for a bit.  Since the Venom symbiote first bonded with Parker, it is likely that it took the knowledge of how to create webs from Peter's mind.

Carnage, Venom's offspring, also uses web-like extrusions to swing.  Unlike Venom, he seems to retract these extrusions into his being again after swinging.  He is almost never seen to mimic any of Spidey's other tricks (such as impact webbing or even encasing people in webbing).  It isn't clear if this is because he refuses to leave behind his body mass (since his extrusions are clearly part of himself, as opposed to Venom's) or because he is unable.

This discrepancy between the two symbiotes is what leads me to believe Venom produces 'real' webs (duplicated from Spider-man's) while Carnage does not.